# How to change navigation item title via interface builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, navigationcontroller

Ran into an issue today.

I embedded a table view controller in a navigation controller. That table view is linked to two other view controllers via segues - the first is one to connect from table view controller to a log in view controller, the second is a manual segue to connect from a button control (in that log in view controller) to a sign up view controller.

All of these three view controllers look to be successfully embedded in the navigation controller as all of them have the navigation bar on the top.

Sadly I can't seem to set the title of the navigation bar for them all. I wanted the title to be the same for them all. I can set the title in the table view controller which is embedded in the navigation controller, but I can't seem to set the title for the other two.

I can double click into these two navigation bars and type in some text, but this text doesn't save.

Can anyone help me set the same title for all, using the Interface Builder (don't want to o this in code at the moment, unless I have no other choice!).

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the title for whichever view controller that you want:

[image]

Doing it programmatically isn't complicated at all, either. All you need to do is to add this line in the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller:

```
- viewDidLoad
{
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
}
```

Comment: I thought that worked but i came back to it just now and actually the problem was that my navigation bar is overlapping my username textfield - my topmost ui element. Can you help??

Comment: Hmm... Do you mean that the navigation stack doesn't pop and push view controllers as it should?